# Problem with function callback with using stateflow chart in 2019b MATLAB/Simulink version

Tags: matlab, callback, simulink

I have two models in Simulink. Master (A) and slave (B) with is linked by Referenced Model block to model A. In the future i want to refer more models in A. Model B has two function-call subsystems (Init and Periodic). I want to call them from model A with different order and number of times. To do this I prepared stateflow chart with suitable logic. I have two versions of Simulink, 2021b and 2019b. In 2021b everything works properly. The problem is when I want to run this simulation in 2019b version. For example model prepared in 2019b not work in it but if I want to use the same file in 2021b I don't have any issues. I tired to resolve this problem by couple of days without any resulst. For now I have no idea. I have to use version 2019b and there is no possibility to change. Below are screenshots from the simulink and a description of the error. Maybe it is possible to ignore this error by turnig off some diagnostic option, but which? I will be greatuful for any help. Thank you.
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oajm.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjJmq.jpg)

I tried to change some errors control in diagnostic settings but without any resulsts.

Comment: i think it is a simulation time misalignment. Meaning that the simulation time starts at 0.00 and your periodic call has it's first occurrence at 0.001 while simulink,for some reason,  expects it at 0.00. Probably you have some solver settings differences beween your matlabs